# How to keep 3rd party's site credentials with GAE?

Tags: google-app-engine, authorization

My GAE site should communicate with 3rd party site (i.e. should use it's API).
That 3rd party site requires HTTP Digest Authentication.
To support that I use the following header, it works well:

```
headers={'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % base64.b64encode('login:pass')}
```

How can I check if authorization on that side is still valid and if it is not, how should I ask user to input login and pass again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the authentication details are not valid, the site will return a `401 Unauthorized` response. The only way to check for validity is to make a request - any request - and see if you get a 401.

How you prompt the user for updated credentials depends entirely on your application, how it's designed, and who your users are.

Comment: Thanks. When authorization happened first time, don't I receive some details about the same? i.e. validity period? Looks like the best approach would be to save result base64 data in the memcache for some time and use that in each request. Once memcache data is not available already - request user to input that again.

Comment: @LA_ No - HTTP authentication doesn't implement any sort of scoping, etc. There's no reason the server would even have a vaility period - you're sending the username and password (and thus authenticating fresh) with each new request. I would not recommend relying on memcache exclusively to store the data - store it in the datastore as a backup.

Comment: Thanks, Nick. I think the best approach would be to store that in user's cookie - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544197/how-to-set-cookies-with-gae-python-for-1-month

Comment: @LA_ I wouldn't recommend it - cookies aren't designed to store secure credentials, and they'll be transmitted between your user and your site on every request.